How to make all raycasts ingore a specific collider
I need to make a collider that cannot be hit by any raycasts. I'm a server plugin dev so I can't modify anything about base game raycasts (technically I can but there is a lot of them and trying to change every single one with transpilers will take to much time). This also means that I cannot use Unity editor and have to do everything in code.
P.S: The game in question is SCP Secret Laboratory.

Just all the colliders' GameObjects use a layer that's in the Physics.IgnoreRaycastLayer LayerMask, or add a new layer to that list. By default, Unity already has an "Ignore Raycast" layer with id 2.
This won't work if all the existing Raycasts include that layer in their own layerMask parameter, but it's probably really unlikely for a game to use all 32 available layers.
